# ServiceStack AutoQuery, Multiple IJoin

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In my example I have the following database structure. `Order` has many `OrderLine`, which has one `Product`.

[image: Image illustrating the above description.]

I am trying to return the following DTO:

```
public class OrderLineDto {
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int Quantity { get; set; }
   public string OrderType { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

This should be possible by use of the following Query Route:

```
[Route("/orderlines")]
public class FindOrderLines : QueryBase<OrderLine, OrderLineDto>,
  IJoin<OrderLine, Order>, 
  IJoin<OrderLine, Product>
{ }
```

What I am trying to do here is join OrderLine in both directions to bring in Type from Order, and Name from Product and return it in an OrderLineDto.

I am able to do these things individually by only using one `IJoin`, however AutoQuery appears only to use the first `IJoin` interface declaration, and does not perform the second join.

If I attempt to do a join like this: `IJoin<OrderLine, Order, Product>`

I get the following exception: `Could not infer relationship between Order and Product`

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do here with auto query or should I go back to writing standard REST services, abandoning AutoQuery?

Comment: Diving into ServiceStack, I can see that AppendJoins in TypedQuery only uses the first IJoin interface, there should be no reason why this could not go though each IJoin interface on the class, could this be added in the next version? (Currently 4.0.33)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted a pull request to ServiceStack which will now allow this behavior.

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/pull/955